# Msqli PHP fetch_object

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I am using a mysqli login system on my website for which the files i have included here:

(login.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'classes/Membership.php';
$membership = new Membership();

// If the user clicks the "Log Out" link on the index page.
if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'loggedout') {
    $membership->log_User_Out();
}

// Did the user enter a password/username and click submit?
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
}


?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

etc.
```

That is the main html file and the following are the php files:

(membership.php);

```
<?php

require 'Mysql.php';

class Membership {

    function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
        $mysql = New Mysql();
        $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

        if($ensure_credentials) {
            $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
proposed session variable:  $_SESSION['name'] = 'RESULT';
            header("location: index.php");
        } else return "Please enter a correct username and password";

    } 

    function log_User_Out() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['status']);

            if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) 
                setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 1000);
                session_destroy();
        }
    }

    function confirm_Member() {
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['status'] !='authorized') header("location: login.php");
    }

}
?>
```

(mysql.php):

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

class Mysql {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
                      die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }

    function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

        $query = "SELECT *
                FROM players_login
                WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
                LIMIT 1";

        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
    My Attempt: $row = $query->fetch_object();
            $stmt->execute();


            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Right my query is I would like the server to echo the user's Name in the index.php saying for example `Hello: Jane Thompson` an have the ability to use that name when they post anything to the database i.e: `Posted By: Jane Thompson`.

Comment: Please note that greetings and signatures should not be included in questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950 ;-)

Comment: Did you really just say _Feel free to change the code around just s long as it works_ ? I think you'd might have misunderstood what we do here...

Comment: sorry i just need to know why it is giving me an error. No offence intended. I just would like some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could save in $_SESSION the username and password like:

```
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

so in index.php you could print

```
<div>Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['user']?></div>
```

Comment: Actually thank you your code has made me thin of a workaround. Great thanks!!

Comment: manage DB to have a table like this: username | pass | dispName. $stmt->fetch() does not return the row/s?